# Black screen when starting X

Tags: x11, opensuse

I have two systems. The only real difference between them is that one is OpenSUSE 12.2, and the other is OpenSUSE 13.1. Oh yeah, and that the 12.2 box *works*, while the 13.1 one doesn't.

Basically, when I start X, I get a black screen. The other VTs still work just fine, but X doesn't. The most bizarre thing is that all the logs *seem* to indicate that X is functioning just fine. (!) The only error message I can find is this:

```
xdm[524]: Starting service gdm..done
xdm[524]: Failed to give slave programs access to the display. Trying to proceed.
xdm[524]: can't open /etc/X11/Xresources
xdm[524]: /usr/bin/xrdb: No such file or directory
xdm[524]: /usr/bin/xrdb: can't open file '/etc/X11/Xresources'
```

(This appears near the end of `/var/log/messages`.)

On the working system, the *first* message appears, but none of the following ones.

The file `/etc/X11/Xresources` does not exist on either of the two systems. Yet one works, and the other doesn't.

Is this error message the source of my troubles, or is this a red herring? Any ideas what I might have done wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

It appears that I configured X to auto-login as a specific user, but on the broken box that user doesn't exist. (!) Apparently trying to auto-login as a non-existent user is a Bad Idea. (Not, of course, that anything could give me an error message to *say* that that was the problem...)